# CakePHP help in blog tutorial - Simple Authentication and Authorization Application

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0

I need help in the CakePHP - Simple Authentication and Authorization Application Tutorial

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {
    // All registered users can add posts
    if ($this->action === 'add') {
        return true;
    }

    // The owner of a post can edit and delete it
    if (in_array($this->action, array('edit', 'delete'))) {
        $postId = $this->request->params['pass'][0];
        if ($this->Post->isOwnedBy($postId, $user['id'])) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return parent::isAuthorized($user);
}
```

this part I don't know what does this means I already searched on google but I found none

```
$this->Post->isOwnedBy($postId, $user['id'])
```

Comment: Did you read the paragraph in the tutorial right under that code block where it says "A final thing is left to be implemented, to tell whether the user is authorized to edit the post or not, we’re calling a isOwnedBy() function in the Post model."?

Comment: Oh my, I didn't noticed that thanks lol

Answer (score 5):

`isOwnedBy` is a function in post model `Post.php` which override `AppController's` `isAuthorized` function to know if post is made by this user or not. If not then allow him to access `add` action otherwise allow to access `add` ,`edit` , `delete`

Read this for more details [Cake book- authorization-who-s-allowed-to-access-what](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authorization-who-s-allowed-to-access-what)